Alpakka Big Query connector TimeOut Exception after 6 minutes
I'm having a Akka stream application with big query as source, that queries a table. This is implemented using Akka Alpakka Big query connector.
here is the code snippet for that.
val timeOut = 30.minutes
//QueryRequest(query, maxResults, defaultDataset, timeout, dryRun, useLegacySql, None, None, None, requestId)
val request = QueryRequest(query, None, None, Some(timeOut), Some(false), Some(false), None) 
val source = Source[T, Future[QueryResponse[T]]]BigQuery.query[T](request)

Though I've configured timeout of 30 minutes, I get below exception after 6 minutes.
akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Query job not complete.
    at akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.BigQueryException$.apply(BigQueryException.scala:19)
    at akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.BigQueryException$.apply(BigQueryException.scala:28)
    at akka.stream.alpakka.googlecloud.bigquery.scaladsl.BigQueryQueries.$anonfun$query$9(BigQueryQueries.scala:101)

The timeout seems to be working for any values less than 3 minutes, but beyond that I'm getting this exception after 6 minutes.
Any configuration missing here.
